# How to use reraise in async workflows in F#?

Tags: asynchronous, exception, f#, f#-async

I needed to reraise an exception that occurs while executing an async block, after logging the exception.

When I do the following the compiler thinks that I am not calling the reraise function from within the handler. What am I doing wrong?

```
let executeAsync context = async {
    traceContext.Properties.Add("CorrelationId", context.CorrelationId)
    try
        do! runAsync context
        return None
    with
        | e when isCriticalException(e) ->
            logCriticalException e
            reraise()
        | e ->
            logException e
            return Some(e)
}
```

Comment: I have submitted this as an F# suggestion, could I have your upvotes folks? https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/660

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rough! I think this is impossible, because reraise corresponds to a special IL instruction that grabs the exception from the top of the stack, but the way async expressions are compiled into a chain of continuations, I don't think the semantics hold!

For the same reason, the following won't compile either:

```
try
    (null:string).ToString()
with e ->
    (fun () -> reraise())()
```

In these situations, where I need to handle the exception outside of the actual `with` body, and would like to emulate `reraise` (that is, preserve the stack trace of the exception), I use [this](http://iridescence.no/post/Preserving-Stack-Traces-When-Re-Throwing-Inner-Exceptions.aspx) solution, so all together your code would look like:

```
let inline reraisePreserveStackTrace (e:Exception) =
    let remoteStackTraceString = typeof<exn>.GetField("_remoteStackTraceString", BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    remoteStackTraceString.SetValue(e, e.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);
    raise e

let executeAsync context = async {
    traceContext.Properties.Add("CorrelationId", context.CorrelationId)
    try
        do! runAsync context
        return None
    with
        | e when isCriticalException(e) ->
            logCriticalException e
            reraisePreserveStackTrace e
        | e ->
            logException e
            return Some(e)
}
```

**Update:** .NET 4.5 introduced [ExceptionDispatchInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) which may allow a cleaner implementation of `reraisePreserveStackTrace` above.

Comment: This answer is perhaps outdated.  In .net 4.5 you can use the `ExceptionDispatchInfo` class, which does this and also captures Watson bucket info such as assembly of origin and IL offset.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DaxFohl could please provide an updated answer using `ExceptionDispatchInfo`?

Comment: I have submitted this as an F# suggestion, could I have your upvotes guys? https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/660

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in comments and updates to answers, you can use `ExceptionDispatchInfo` as a workaround.

```ml
open System.Runtime.ExceptionServices

let inline reraiseAnywhere<'a> (e: exn) : 'a =
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(e).Throw()
    Unchecked.defaultof<'a>
```

Usage:

```ml
async {
    try
         do! someAsyncThing ()
         return "Success"
    with
    | e ->
        if errorIsOk e then return "Handled error"
        else return (reraiseAnyWhere e)
}
```

Here is a GitHub [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JamesFaix/af0bab95aca867ae2d1b7c2c2de2a658) I made with unit tests to check its behavior.

Comment: Nice solution. Just wondering why you are returning `Unchecked.defaultof<'a>`. And why the use of type parameters? Would it not always be returning `unit`?

Comment: In the example, the async block is of type `Async<string>` so each `return` expression must return a `string`. So `reraiseAnywhere` needs to be typed as returning `'a` even though it never actually returns any value.

Comment: nice answer! the stack trace is unchanged too

Answer (score 5):

I ran in to a similar problem, in a different context, but it boils down to this.

Exceptions cannot be thrown onto a different thread - calling `reraise()` would require an exception handler running in some sense 'above' the original async block in the code.

```
let runAsync context = async {return ()}
let isCriticalException e = true
let logCriticalException e = ()
let logException e = ()
let executeAsync context = 
    async {
            do! runAsync context
            return None
}

let run = 
    match executeAsync 5 |> Async.Catch |> Async.RunSynchronously with
    |Choice1Of2(t) -> 
        printfn "%A" t
        None
    |Choice2Of2(exn) ->  
            match exn with
            | e when isCriticalException(e) ->
                logCriticalException e
                raise (new System.Exception("See inner exception",e)) //stack trace will be lost at this point if the exn is not wrapped
            | e ->
                logException e
                Some(e)
```

Note, we still can't use reraise, as we are now calling on a different thread, so we wrap the exception inside another one

Comment: It's more specific then not being able to call reraise from a different thread, it can't be called from a different stackframe.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [`@JamesFaix'`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72132958/11635)...

See https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/660

---

Place this in an `Infrastructure.fs` file:

```ml
namespace global

type Exception with
    // https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/660
    member this.Reraise() =
        System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(this).Throw()
        Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

Usage example:

```
let! client = async {
     try return! CosmosStoreClient.Connect(x, databaseId, containers)
     with e -> Log.Error(e, "Could not connect to {databaseId}/{containers}", databaseId, containers)
               return e.Reraise() }
```